# Only get files younger than t

Tags: vb.net, directory, getfiles

Is there a way to get only the files out of a directory which are younger than a specific age?

So this method will produce this result, but it will get all files first and then disregard those who dont fit, which is quite inefficient.

`Dim Files = dir.GetFiles().Where(Function(x) x.LastWriteTime >= ts) 'dir: DirectoryInfo, ts: DateTime`

Comment: Replace GetFiles with [EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @Steve I don't think that will actually change the behavior of getting all files and disregarding those that don't fit.  I guess it depends on whether the concern is with the storage required to get all of the file names (probably not really that substantial) or with the disk access required to inspect every file.

Comment: I wanted to ask why EnumerateFiles behave that way, but ok now that its in question... There are multiple thousand elements and the selection barely ever reaches 1% of those. So I would consider it at least inefficient, even when performance is still good

Comment: You can write your own `Iterator` function, enumerate the files and `Yield` only those that match the criteria you defined. To find matches, you need to parse all files anyway, just handle those you care about.